# Paste text in Photoshop without losing the line breaks

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Whenever I copy and paste text (from any source) into Photoshop it all ends up on one line. Then I have to adjust it by hand. Is there a way to preserve the original line breaks?

System: Photoshop CS6, Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Are you aksing to keep the font styles from say a website to be applied to Photoshop text when pasting? Kinda like when you paste into word you can match formatting or keep plain text.

Comment: Hi Metz, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

Create a text box (click and drag) with the type tool. The text will still be on one line when you paste into the text box but you will have more control over the width of the paragraph text box.

Do note that Photoshop is not intended to be a layout program like InDesign.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewH. When you create the text box using the **Text** tool to create a rectangle, you have the control to be able to make the paragraph your desired shape. Then, press "T" (**Text** tool short cut), click inside the text box, and paste. This is more in line with an InDesign textbox, but still does not act the same. *Side note: If you go to **Transform** this text box, it will transform the actual size/shape/width/height of the text unless you select the **Text** tool or press" T" again. While in text mode, you can change the shape of the box again.*